# How to read it from the properties file in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, application.properties

application.properties file has:

```
my.greeting = Hello
```

ServiceClass file has:

```
@Value("${my.greeting}")
private String messageFromProperties;
```

MainAppfile:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplicationConceptsApplication.class, args);
        ServiceClass serv = new ServiceClass();`enter code here`
        System.out.println(serv.getMessageFromProperties());//getting null
    }
```

Please let me know what am i missing here. What all configuration is pending

Comment: Can you show the complete MainAppfile and ServiceClass ?

Comment: You are creating a new instance instead of using the spring managed one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@PropertySource` to specify the source.
For example:

```
@PropertySource(value = "example.properties")
```

You can use the above-mentioned annotation with your main class.
For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = "example.properties")
public class ExampleApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Or, you can use them with classes annotated with `@Configuration`.
For example:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("example.properties")
public class ExampleConfiguration {
    //code
}
```

If this doesn't help, I would advise you to share your complete code for everyone to understand what exactly the problem is.